# Why it's different using java's nanoTime() on Windows and on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I hava two machines on which there are two types of system: one is Windows 10 while the other is Ubuntu.

When I invoke the mehod

```
System.nanoTime()
```

I got two different results on the two machines.

On win10, the Long value of its output is start with '21' and has length of 14; Shocking that on Linux the value is start with '11521' and has length of 17.

How could that be? Why the results are different?

Appreciate for any response.

Comment: [This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: May be this discussion will help you - http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=13657.0